# How to post data on another web page using HTMLAgility pack?

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, html-agility-pack, dopostback

I need to post data on another web page using HTMLAgility pack.

For example, 
http://www.riversoft.mk/Products.aspx
on this web site I need to iterate through the pages of the list view using HTMLAgility pack. 
But when I click some page number then _*dopostback method is called. For that reason I need to find a way to simulate a client click which will invoke this method (*_dopostback(....)).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So, all __doPostBack does is set a couple of hidden form fields and submit. You can verify this by checking the source:

```
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
```

So, basically, all you should *need* to do is set up these two form fields, and then post the resulting body.